# Ubuntu 22.10 - "blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)" message on boot

Tags: boot, 22.10

After upgrading my Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 22.10, the following sequence of messages started to appear on the boot screen:

```
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
[...]
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
```

This is NOT a blocking error, the boot goes on without any apparent issue and I'm able to use my Ubuntu as usual.
These messages were not present before the upgrade, where does it come from?

My setup:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.10 x86_64
- Kernel: 5.19.0-21-generic
- System manufacturer:  SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
- System product-name:  450R4E/450R5E/450R4V/450R5V/4450RV
- Bios release date:  04/29/2014
- Bios version:  P08RBG.216.140429.ZW
- SecureBoot: Disabled
- CPU: Intel i5-3230M (4) @ 3.2GHz
- GPU 1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
- GPU 2: NVIDIA GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M

Comment: I see these messages in Lubuntu 22.10 too.

Comment: Check the Samsung site for a newer BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema: I've done a fast check and there is not a newer BIOS than the current one. That said, could you explain why do you think that this warning is related to a not-updated BIOS?

Comment: @LorenzKeel Newer kernels sometimes require an updated BIOS, and yours is from 2014. That said, try this... from the GRUB menu, boot to an older kernel, and see if the error goes away. If you have 3 or more kernels to choose from, choose the oldest first, and then try each newer kernel until the error reappears. Report back.

Comment: @LorenzKeel See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=278860

Comment: Same Problem here with newer BIOS (HP Version: N86 Ver. 01.55 Date: 04/02/2022) But as my system boots and it seems to be related to the kernel (according to @heynnema s link, mine is 5.19 as well) I just hope it'll "heal itself" with the next kernel updates.

Comment: Getting the same error with a newer BIOS. I am using kernel 6.1.0-060100rc5-generic, which appears to be a requirement for this machine (4th gen thinkbook 13s) to work properly.

Comment: Web search shows this problem to be pretty widespread. It is occurring for me on a 2 year old mother board (Asus Rog Stix Z490-i) with the latest BIOS. From https://lore.kernel.org/linux-security-module/632d2180-02f8-4a5f-803a-57a6443a60f4@t-8ch.de/T/ it looks like it is harmless and they are working on improving the logs.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem both on Ubuntu 22.10 and Fedora 37.  Both distros are using Gnome 43 version. So I think the problem is related to this newer Gnome 43 virsion, and not to the BIOS version.

Comment: @heynnema I'm having the same problem together with this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440379/low-sound-after-upgrading-from-kubuntu-22-04-to-22-10 updated my BIOS to the latest version available everything works well on Win10 boot. can you guide me how to download config and boot with downgraded/earlier kernel version (the latest on v22.04 worked but I don't know what it was) using a dedicated GRUB entry for it? TNX

Comment: @Roey In the Additional Options menu selection in GRUB, do you see older kernels available there to boot? If not, download an older Ubuntu (not Kubuntu) .iso file, burn it to a USB flash device, boot to it, and see if your symptoms are gone.

Comment: Same message started appearing with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Nano Gen 1 / 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1160G7 @ 1.20GHz × 8

Comment: heynnema booted with Kubuntu 22.04.2 USB drive got the same (-13) errors but the sound was fixed 
here are the differences between the 2 boots: 

``Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04 | Kubuntu 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7 | 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0 | 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3 | 5.15.6
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-32-generic (64-bit) | 5.19.0-35-generic (64-bit)``
What could be causing the sound problem? It's  not the kernel I've booted 22.10 with 5.19.0-31 and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Same message reported on Lenovo Thinkpad P14s, with latest BIOS (1.21) and latest stable kernel (5.19). — @Roey if the symptom (-13 errros) are still there with both Ubuntu versions, then for the sound problem is unrelated and you should probably write a new SO question.

Comment: _"These kernel messages should be treated as warning, not error. You should not remove blacklisted hashes (i.e. do not clear secure boot keys), this is a security measure to protect against malicious signatures. These kernel messages now show because we hardened this security mechanism, and it now reveals issues with some firmwares. There is an ongoing kernel patch to update this error message: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/3b997266-0 … gikod.net/"_ \[[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2066881#p2066881)]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can safely ignore it.

> *"These kernel messages should be treated as warning, not error. **You should not remove blacklisted hashes (i.e. do not clear secure boot keys)**, this is a security measure to protect against malicious signatures.
>
> These kernel messages now show because we hardened this security mechanism, and **it now reveals issues with some firmwares**.
>
> There is an ongoing kernel patch to update this error message: [https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/3b997266-067c-975c-911a-da146fe9033a@digikod.net/"](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/3b997266-067c-975c-911a-da146fe9033a@digikod.net/%22)*

as reported in [source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2066881#p2066881).

This is **something that the different manufacturers need to correct in their BIOS/firmware**.
The correct approach (of seeing the messages as a *Warning* instead of an *Error*) is confirmed in the patch discussion:

> *"We should not hide EACCES errors. This logs issues, which is correct for duplicate hashes, and can help firmware vendors to fix their database.
> I'd really like to see a different log message instead: change the
> duplicate entry error code from EACCES to EEXIST, and call pr_warn for
> this specific case."*

You just need to wait for upgrades from your motherboard producer. (Asus, Dell, Lenovo, etc.)
Or contact their support to report the issue and request a fix.

Comment: just wait for an update, if only it were like that. Then again, you missed Dell which is one of the worst when it comes to BIOS code. I recommend regardless to email vendor support, point it out and ask it explicitly : if nobody asks, nothing wlll likely happen.