# Low sound after upgrading from Kubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

Even at 150% speakers output I can barely hear any sound

My sysinfo:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.6
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-35-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500
Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
Product Name: HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13
```

My alsamixer sysinfo output:

```
/proc/asound/version ───────────────────────┐                                              │
│                                             │Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.19.0-31-generic
/proc/asound/cards ─────────────────────────┐                                             │
│                                            │ 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI                      │                                             │
│                                            │                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb2210000 irq 49             │                                             │
│                                            │ 1 [broadwellrt286 ]: broadwell-rt286 - broadwell-rt286               │                                             │
│                                            │                      Hewlett_Packard-HPSpectrex360Convertible13--802D
```

full alsamixer output: https://file.io/N6A14ChrnlLV

Everything worked well on Kubuntu 22.04 and I cannot revert back

Booting 22.04.2 pen drive has sound while booting 22.10 pen drive doesn't

I have a dualboot machine everything works well on Windows 10 so it's not a hardware problem for sure

Thanks

Comment: here is a FULL alsa-info dump of my system http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=496ff0ffb2e4f7921ca9f1a949574130a59b34fb I hope someone can help

Comment: I also got this message/problem after upgrading to 22.10 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436856/ubuntu-22-10-blacklist-problem-blacklisting-hash-13-message-on-boot updating the bios to the latest version available didn't solved either of these problems