# blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)’ errors on boot

Tags: blacklist

When I try to install Ubuntu LTS.. see massage

```
"blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13).
```

What's does this mean?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Same problem, after another auto-renewal of the system. Looks like https://ibb.co/Dk3fHf1 
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: Discussion https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/c8c65713-5cda-43ad-8018-20f2e32e4432@t-8ch.de/T/

Comment: Probably a warning from the kernel that you can ignore, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1457597).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.10 - "blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)" message on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436856/ubuntu-22-10-blacklist-problem-blacklisting-hash-13-message-on-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will be addressed in Kernel 6.3 by reducing the log error message severity to a warning https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c95e8f6fd157b45ef0685c221931561e943e82da

As per advice above, for now ignore the message