# B360M PRO-VH error when install ubuntu

Tags: 23.04, msi

I am using:

- Main B360M PRO-VH version bios 7B53v1C (2022-11-07)
- SSD Samsung 970 EVO Plus PCIe NVMe VNAND M.2 2280

I install Ubuntu 23.04 desktop from the official website (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) from usb boot but the system notifies errors. I try to change more settings in the bios setting but it still error.

[RESOLVE] Edit 20h01 25/05/2023:
My USB has a problem, I change another USB and then install successfully.

Update 12h59 25/05/2023:

- I use Balena etcher, Rufus, Startup Disk Creator (ubuntu) to burn file iso to USB

Is there anybody know why and how to fix it?

Thanks for reading.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your installation media is INVALID: thus the *NO MEDIUM FOUND* messages & eventual offer to download a valid ISO at the bottom of your screen.  You can also get this if you're machine doesn't have sufficient resources for the OS you're trying to install (*easiest to achieve this on VMs by giving it almost no RAM*) but either your downloaded ISO was invalid (did you check it?) or the write of the ISO to media failed (check it on another box).

Comment: You didn't specify which Ubuntu 23.04 product you're trying to install (Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? and which Desktop ISO as there are two options!) but your error messages show invalid media (ISO or ISO write with the write the most common flaw; some apps like `rufus` can only write 23.04 with specific versions too & you gave no clues as to how you wrote ISO & what params/checks you performed; if you used rufus did you note 23.04 instructions!)

Comment: @guiverc: I use Balena etcher, Rufus, Startup Disk Creator (ubuntu) to burn file iso to USB and ubuntu desktop 23.04 from official website, I also follow the work steps Install Ubuntu desktop  tutorial on website

Comment: The option/method of write of ISO matters, ie. direct *clone* (`rufus` calls this a `dd-mode` if I recall correctly) is what is used in QA testing of the ISOs in testing, other methods re-format the ISO to media which will prevent correct operation if booted in a different type of device than the method the ISO write was intended for... (where as *clone* will work in BIOS/uEFI/Secure-uEFI without change). If your issue relates to something specific to your hardware; sorry I'm not familiar with your hardware (& you'll have to wait for others) thus I'm reading the 1st/3rd screen alone.

Comment: For the middle screen you can read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436856/ubuntu-22-10-blacklist-problem-blacklisting-hash-13-message-on-boot for more details; however I didn't see that as critical to your issue.

Comment: @guiverc: thanks for your reply. My USB has a problem, I change another USB and then install successfully.