# "Clean ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks" shows with WMI/WDG on boot, but it boots sucessfully

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, uefi, bios

Each time I boot Ubuntu, this message shows up on my laptop screen below errors and failures, with my HDD making noise for several seconds. However, each time it does not stick boot. The word "hash" appears frequently in the error messages.

Some answers said that it may be caused by NVIDIA. The answer said that I should delete and uninstall something have to do with NVIDIA. But these errors and "clean message" still exists even if I have conducted his or her instructions.

[image: Before that line]

[image: After that line, the font get extremely small]

Output of systemd-analyze blame

```
30.272s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.981s gpu-manager.service
10.248s dev-sda2.device
 8.958s dev-loop12.device
 8.916s dev-loop14.device
 8.078s e2scrub_reap.service
 8.024s dev-loop5.device
 7.406s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 7.176s dev-loop4.device
 7.070s snapd.service
 6.879s networkd-dispatcher.service
 5.456s accounts-daemon.service
 4.878s dev-loop13.device
 4.646s systemd-rfkill.service
 4.563s udisks2.service
 4.556s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C8E4\x2d7965.service
 3.965s NetworkManager.service
 3.392s ModemManager.service
 3.130s dev-loop3.device
 2.786s avahi-daemon.service
 2.785s bluetooth.service
 2.684s cups.service
 2.631s power-profiles-daemon.service
 2.570s polkit.service
 2.547s dev-loop9.device
 2.458s dev-loop10.device
 2.453s dev-loop11.device
 2.407s dev-loop8.device
 2.319s systemd-resolved.service
 2.306s snapd.apparmor.service
 2.284s dev-loop7.device
 1.963s dev-loop6.device
 1.945s dev-loop2.device
 1.919s fwupd.service
 1.702s switcheroo-control.service
 1.699s thermald.service
 1.699s systemd-logind.service
 1.698s wpa_supplicant.service
 1.652s apport.service
 1.489s grub-common.service
 1.453s dev-loop1.device
 1.400s systemd-journal-flush.service
 1.399s secureboot-db.service
 1.289s plymouth-start.service
 1.242s gdm.service
 1.151s dev-loop0.device
 1.113s modprobe@efi_pstore.service
  860ms systemd-modules-load.service
  802ms apparmor.service
  767ms systemd-udevd.service
  745ms rsyslog.service
  682ms snapd.seeded.service
  626ms packagekit.service
  612ms colord.service
  607ms systemd-random-seed.service
  598ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  568ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  497ms systemd-sysusers.service
  492ms systemd-sysctl.service
  472ms systemd-journald.service
  454ms keyboard-setup.service
  424ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  387ms binfmt-support.service
  352ms user@1000.service
  346ms bolt.service
  340ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  336ms snap-core20-2015.mount
  322ms upower.service
  300ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  296ms systemd-oomd.service
  296ms boot-efi.mount
  281ms snap-core20-1974.mount
  269ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  263ms kerneloops.service
  259ms update-notifier-download.service
  257ms modprobe@drm.service
  252ms snap-firefox-3416.mount
  241ms snap-core22-858.mount
  236ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
  204ms ufw.service
  197ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  181ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  180ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  177ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-120.mount
  176ms swapfile.swap
  171ms plymouth-read-write.service
  171ms console-setup.service
  155ms snap-core22-864.mount
  150ms snap-bare-5.mount
  148ms snap-snapd-19457.mount
  147ms snap-snap\x2dstore-959.mount
  128ms systemd-binfmt.service
  111ms snap-firefox-3358.mount
   98ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   93ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-141.mount
   76ms setvtrgb.service
   70ms openvpn.service
   70ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   59ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   56ms dev-hugepages.mount
   55ms dev-mqueue.mount
   55ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   54ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   54ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-83.mount
   49ms snap-snapd-20290.mount
   38ms snapd.socket
   37ms rtkit-daemon.service
   27ms modprobe@configfs.service
   26ms modprobe@fuse.service
   22ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   21ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   21ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   11ms alsa-restore.service
    8ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
    5ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
    3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
```

Comment: we all have that line during boot unless someone changed kernel prms. (`quiet loglevel 0` or `quiet loglevel 1` or `quiet loglevel 2` will suppress this; default is `quiet` and that is equal to `quiet loglevel 3`). A slow boot likely is one of 3: videocard driver, network discovery, of printer discovery. Check your boot log to see timings of your boot. `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and insert the output of: `systemd-analyze blame | head`.

Comment: "*with my HDD making noise for several seconds*" That's suspicious. Modern HDDs should be almost silent under just about all circumstances.

Comment: Maybe my description is not precise. But the HDD really makes SLIGHT noise. it makes almost no noise when just spinning.

Comment: You might want to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436856/ubuntu-22-10-blacklist-problem-blacklisting-hash-13-message-on-boot  Looks like a BIOS update of your system might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

###### TLDR? Go to "Bottom line" ... Otherwise:

`Clean ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks` is not your problem ... It probably, almost certainly, happens on most computers at most boots and a simple:

```
sudo grep -E -- '---.*---|clean.*files.*blocks' /var/log/boot*
```

... will reveal it had happened multiple times on multiple boots, but is hidden with the splash screen so goes unnoticed most of the time ... That is until some other message that needs attention e.g. an actual warning/error is printed and then it's shown among other printed lines but it's not an error or even a warning in itself.

The warnings/errors that show in your screenshots are actually due to a failed communication between the Ubuntu's kernel and your computer's BIOS/UEFI firmware related to WMI and WDG ... In such miscommunication situation, those messages are most likely ambiguous, so shouldn't be taken for granted.

[WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)<sup>(*Windows Management Instrumentation*)</sup> and [WDG/WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg)<sup>(*Windows Debugger/Debugging*)</sup> are both Microsoft Windows related technologies with the former being on the computer's firmware side and the latter being on the Windows OS side ... In short, your computer is solely designed for the Microsoft Windows OS ... And it's not just your computer, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198969) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1217974) for example and it's more common than it appears these days.

Likewise, some sub technologies/devices on those platforms might be designed as well to be best handled by a proprietary driver designed for the Windows OS and is only made available for Windows ... In fact some [CIRRUS LOGIC](https://www.cirrus.com/index.html) chips fall within this criteria like [CS35L41](https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs35l41/) and the error you have is discussed [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215993) and [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/platform-driver-x86/patch/20211217115708.882525-9-tanureal@opensource.cirrus.com/).

That said, the Ubuntu<sup>(*Linux*)</sup> kernel has ways and sub-systems that can translate, understand and mimic those technologies and it shouldn't be a big issue and most of the time wont affect functionality aside from the confusing error messages like the ones you see ... It might be worth noting though that in some cases, although a minority, the computer's functionality is hindered particularly things related to [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI)<sup>(*Advanced Configuration and Power Interface*)</sup>.

It might be worth noting that those issues are reliant on either BIOS/UEFI support for the Linux kernel or Linux kernel's support for BIOS/UEFI or both ... So, upgrading your BIOS/UEFI firmware or your Ubuntu's OS kernel could very probably bring a fix with it.

**Bottom line** is if your system functions as expected, then you can ignore those warnings/errors related to WMI/WDG.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But how should I update my UEFI firmware? My Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS, and I don't know if its kernel is the latest version.

Comment: @RobertH. You are welcome. Your UEFI or BIOS firmware comes from the manufacturer/vendor of your motherboard/PC so check in their website for your specific model ... Newer kernels come with newer Ubuntu releases. A newer release exists and you can upgrade to it 23.04 or even 23.10 (although not LongTermSupport). Also  24.04 is coming in a few months.