# How to debug ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0] AE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I get the following error when booting

[image]

I found several related problems:

- [blacklist-problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436856/ubuntu-22-10-blacklist-problem-blacklisting-hash-13-message-on-boot)
- [ACPI Error message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot)

Is there any way to check wether it is a hardware or a bios problem?
I have windows as a dual boot on the same hard drive but different partition and it is working without a problem.

Comment: You don't.  see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot I'd focus on the blacklist issue. And your disc if those inode errors keep repeating.

Comment: But could you give me a hint, how I can solve the problem? 
Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu entirely? I canot access Ubuntu in order to update it.